# globals()メソッドは何の為に使うものなのか

Tags: python

globals()メソッドは何の為に使うものでしょうか？
コードの中に、

```
test = globals()
```

という行が出てきて、この行がどういう機能を持っているのかわからず苦戦しています・・・。
調べたところ、モジュールを返すものみたいですが、何のモジュールを返すのかわからないです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「モジュールを返す」ではなく、「モジュール内のグローバル変数を返す」です。

頻繁に使うものではないので、そのコードが何のために使ってるのかは推測できませんが、グローバル変数の一覧を取得したかったのかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「モジュール内のグローバル変数」とは、例えばmath.fabsメソッド内で使われているグローバル変数の一覧を取得するという事でしょうか？また、グローバル変数の一覧を取得する必要があるときをもしご存知でしたら教えてください、宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: いいえ、それはfabsのローカル変数です。グローバル変数やスコープについては以下を参照してください。 https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces
一覧を取得する必要性は、ほとんどの場合ありません。